# Dismiss PopupWindow on touch outside popup, without using deprecated constructor

Tags: android, popupwindow

I have a PopupWindow and I wanted it to dismiss when the user touches outside, so I looked into and found out that I had to use `popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());`. The problem is that the constructor `new BitmpaDrawable()` is deprecated. I Would like to find a solution without using it.

Anybody knows how to solve this?

Thanks!

```
                final PopupWindow popup = new PopupWindow(sortByView,
                                          ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                                          ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,            
                                          true);
                popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
                popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
                popup.showAsDropDown(v);
```

Comment: popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.R.color.transparent));

Answer (score 19):

What I had to do to get it to work:

```
popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(ContextCompat.getColor(context, android.R.color.transparent)));
popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
```

Comment: I have tried same thing and it is working in emulator but the same code is not working on device. what can be the issue?

Answer (score 7):

Hmm setBackgroundDrawable don't dissmiss popup window. I think that default behavior of popup window is to dismiss on touching outside but you may add onDismiss listener like that

```
popup.setOnDismissListener(new PopupWindow.OnDismissListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDismiss() {
        popup.dismiss();
        // end may TODO anything else                   
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think that the default behavior of popup windows is to dismiss, if I don't use the line `popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());` the popup doesn't dismiss on touch out . It only does with that line, but `new BitmapDrawable()` is deprecated so I get a warning that I want to avoid.

Comment: How do you show popup? If you show it with popup.showAsDropDown() when you call 'popup.dismiss()' that dismiss popup window. Check your code whether do you have a line 'popup.setOutsideTouchable(true)'. And try with: popup.setModal(true)

Comment: Yes, I am using `popup.showAsDropDown(v);` . PopupWindow has not a method `popup.setModal(true)`

Comment: Ok i'm sorry for previous, but remove line popup.setOutsideTouchable(true);, because that controls whether the pop-up will be informed of touch events outside of its window and after that you will not have a this problem.

Answer (score 7):

You could try.

```
popup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),
            ""));
```