# "Avoid passing null as the view root" with popupwindow

Tags: android, android-layout, null, popupwindow, layout-inflater

So, my program works fine. I only have three warnings left (one for each popupwindow) and it annoys me alot, I've been serching around for a solution that would fit my needs but I can't seem to find one.

This is my code (the other two popupwindows are similar)

```
else if(id == R.id.action_resetstats){
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater  = (LayoutInflater)getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.resetpop, null);
        final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        Button yesDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.yesDismiss);
        yesDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(savedData, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                Editor editor = prefs.edit();
                editor.clear();
                editor.commit();

                counterW = 0;
                counterL = 0;
                counterT = 0;
                counterTot = 0;
                timerTime = 3;

                popupWindow.dismiss();
            }
        });    

        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(yeDismiss, 50, 50);


        Button noDismiss = (Button)popupView.findViewById(R.id.noDismiss);
        noDismiss.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v){
                popupWindow.dismiss();
            }
        });    

        popupWindow.showAsDropDown(naDismiss, 50, 50);
```

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
android:layout_margin="5dp"
android:background="@android:color/black"
android:orientation="vertical"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="230dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_margin="2dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/noDismiss"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="NO!" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="       Reset stats?"
            android:textSize="22sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/yesDismiss"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Yes" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:text="Are you sure you want " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="to reset your statistics?" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="39dp"
        android:text="!CANNOT BE UNDONE!" />

</RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is here to clear things up:

```
View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.resetpop, null);
```

and the warning says:

```
Avoid passing null as the view root (needed to resolve layout parameters on the inflated layout's root element)
```

Any ideas how to solve this the best way? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Forgot to add the warning. Should be edited now.

Comment: I see. You should usually provide the parent layout, in order to copy its layout constraints. In your case I think, you can simple ignore the warning

Comment: Ah, good thing to know that I may ignore it atleast. I'm very new to programming of any sort so any knowledge is really helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could just use:

```
context = popupView.getContext();
inflater.inflate(R.layout.resetpop, new LinearLayout(context), false);
```

That should solve the warning.

Comment: It does not make sense to construct a fake parent. I would rather simply suppress the warning.

Answer (score 1):

When you write below code blog, you mean inflate this layout with parent, attach it to parent, but because of pass null, inflater wont be able to attach new parent

```
View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.resetpop, null);
```

[LayoutInflater class -->](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.0.3_r1/android/view/LayoutInflater.java#LayoutInflater.inflate%28org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParser%2Candroid.view.ViewGroup%2Cboolean%29)

```
  350
  351    public View More ...inflate(int resource, ViewGroup root) {
  352        return inflate(resource, root, root != null);
  353    }
```

But this, it will inflate with given parent, but wont attach it to the new parent.

```
View popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.resetpop, new LinearLayout(context), false);
```

Comment: He doesn't need to. Like he said, his code was working fine, he just wanted to get rid of the warnings. The false in the inflate method is practiacally the same as passing NULL (just like you state with your code snippet) but won't raise any warnings.

Comment: it is just a more information :) I know that your answer is true

Answer (score -1):

**PopupWindow Performance Issues and Unable Dismiss**

In case someone stumbled upon here, because of some performance issues on the `PopupWindow`.

It is when your had the `PopupWindow` launched, but just freezes the entire screen and without able proceed unless restarting the app. Happens on older devices, mine happened to be Samsung GT-N7100 (API 19).

Well, I've tried with solving the warning when using the `LayoutInflater`. But, didn't solve the lagging issue.

**Step 1 - Set View to Render Using Software Acceleration**

According to this forum post, all I need is to set the view to use software acceleration for the view instead. Then, everything is just right as rain.

https://androidforums.com/threads/android-popupwindow-performance-issues.882794/

```
val popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_tooltip, null)
popupView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null)
```

**Step 2 - Set PopupWindow Focusable Attributes to Dismiss**

Immediately after that, I still have issues dismissing the `PopupWindow`. If only the focusable is set to true, the performance issue will still persist.

I have to manually set the attributes to allow it to be dismissed when a click is detected.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45408724/2867351

```
val popupWindow = PopupWindow(popupView, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)

popupWindow.isFocusable = true
popupWindow.isOutsideTouchable = true
popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
```

That's about it. Cheers mate