# event open/close popupWindow

Tags: android, events, popupwindow

I'm trying to create a kind of popupMenuItem with a popupWindow and a custom layout.

I have a button which shows the popupWindow when I click on it. And I would like to trigger and event to dismiss this popupWindow when I click on this button one more time or when I click outside of the popupWindow.

But at the moment it doesn't work, my setTouchInterceptor is not triggered, have you got an idea to solve this problem ?

Each time this popupWindow is open, I can't have access to all the others UI elements even with a setOutsideTouchable(true).

Here my code:

- popupMenuImageView is my dropdown button (imageview actually) which shows my popup window
- popupWindow my global variable for my PopupWindod object.

  ```
  popupMenuImageView = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.popup_menu_imageView);

  popupMenuImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
      @Override
      public void onClick(View v) {

          if (popupWindow == null) {
              int width = 375;
              int height = 240;

              TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.custom_popup_menu_id);
              LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
              View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_popup_menu, tableLayout);

              popupWindow = new PopupWindow(layout, width, height, true);
              popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
              popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
              popupWindow.setTouchInterceptor(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                  @Override
                  public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                      if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE){
                          popupWindow.dismiss();
                          return true;
                      }
                      return false;
                  }
              });

          }
          popupWindow.showAsDropDown(popupMenuImageView);
      }
  });
  ```

Also I've tried this which didn't work too:

```
popupMenuImageView = (ImageView) getView().findViewById(R.id.popup_menu_imageView);
createMenuItem();
popupMenuImageView.setOnClickListener(eventOpenCloseMenuItem);

View.OnClickListener eventOpenCloseMenuItem = new View.OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isShowing) {
                popupWindow.showAsDropDown(popupMenuImageView);
                isShowing = false;
            }else{
                popupWindow.dismiss();
            }
        }
    };
```

> private void createMenuItem(){
>
> ```
>         if (popupWindow == null) {
>             int width = 375;
>             int height = 240;
>
>             TableLayout tableLayout = (TableLayout) getView().findViewById(R.id.custom_popup_menu_id);
>             LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
>             View layout = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_popup_menu, tableLayout);
>
>             popupWindow = new PopupWindow(layout, width, height, true);
>             popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(false);
>             popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
>         }
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to dismiss the popup window by clicking outside of it you don't need to set interceptor. Just set background drawable to null e.g

```
popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable (new BitmapDrawable());
popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
```

and remove:

```
popupWindow.setTouchInterceptor(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE){
                    popupWindow.dismiss();
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Please check my answer to similar question here [PopupWindow - Dismiss when clicked outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232724/popupwindow-dismiss-when-clicked-outside/12232775#12232775)

Comment: BitmapDrawable() is depreciated, instead I have to use ColorDrawable()

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to `setBackgroundDrawable()` before displaying the popup in order for it to handle touch events:

```
popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable());
```