# Dismiss PopupWindow in Fragment when click outside

Tags: java, android, android-popupwindow

I have a Fragment with PopupWindow. I initiate Popup with following code:

```
    private PopupWindow createPopup;

    private void initiateWindow(){
        try {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getActivity()
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.window_popup,
                    (ViewGroup) v.findViewById(R.id.popup_element));
            DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
            int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
            int width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;


            createPopup = new PopupWindow(layout, width/2 + width/4, height/3, true);
            createPopup.showAtLocation(layout, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);


} catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
```

It runs perfectly fine. I want to close the window whenever I click outside. This is a common thing to do, so there are plenty of tutorials and questions regarding the topic around the internet. The problem is - none of them work.

I tried using `createPopup.setBackgroundDrawable(newColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
            createPopup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
            createPopup.setFocusable(true);`
and similar [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232724/popupwindow-dismiss-when-clicked-outside).

I also checked whether I can fill everything behind the popup with solid color using this `createPopup.setBackgroundDrawable(newColorDrawable(Color.BLACK));`, to verify whether I've got wrong core code, but it didn't help either - everything not related to popup layout remained visible.

Comment: it will auto close when click outside it. isn't not closing?

Comment: ok no problem what pop windows contain what view textviews?

Comment: I don't quite follow what you're asking. Anyways, I've provided all the code that could influence popup itself.

Comment: i was planing for foucs change listener but no need o it.

Answer (score 0):

Closes the popup window when touch outside of it - when looses focus

```
createPopup.setOutsideTouchable(true);
createPopup.setFocusable(true);
```

Removes default black background

```
createPopup.setBackgroundDrawable(new ShapeDrawable());
```

if  `ShapeDrawable()` didt work use this one

```
createPopup.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
```

[Same thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232724/popupwindow-dismiss-when-clicked-outside)

Comment: I've already tried that approach. And I tried to add black background to check whether there IS actually a background - there's not unfortunately.

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232724/popupwindow-dismiss-when-clicked-outside

Answer (score 0):

Create a new xml style as shown below.

```
<style name="AppTheme.PopupWindow">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsFloating">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowCloseOnTouchOutside">true</item>
</style>
```

All you need to do after creating the theme is apply it to the fragmentactivity in the manifest.

```
<activity android:name=".PopupWindow" android:theme="@style/AppTheme.PopupWindow"></activity>
```

Comment: The .java class is `Fragment` not `FragmentActivity`. It's not declared in manifest.