# How do I enable a popup to close when clicked outside of it?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-popupwindow

I am trying to make a popup that is going to have text fields and information to ask the user but I am wondering how to make it so that the user can close it by clicking outside of the popup where the main fragment / activity is.

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabstudygroups, container, false);

        listview = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.clist2);
        addCourseButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.caddcoursebutton);

        // do stuff here

        addCourseButton.setOnClickListener(this);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v == addCourseButton) {
            View popupView = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.popup_layout, null);
            final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);

            // HERE IS WHAT I THOUGHT WOULD MAKE IT BE ABLE TO ENABLE THE OUTSIDE TOUCH
            popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable());
            popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

            Button btn = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.button);

            popupWindow.showAsDropDown(popupView, 0, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PopupWindow - Dismiss when clicked outside](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232724/popupwindow-dismiss-when-clicked-outside)

Comment: I gave you wrong answer please have a look here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3121232/android-popup-window-dismissal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your  `PopupWindow` to wrap_content and make it focusable.

```
final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            // HERE IS WHAT I THOUGHT WOULD MAKE IT BE ABLE TO ENABLE THE OUTSIDE TOUCH
            popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
            popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
            popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));


            Button btn = (Button) popupView.findViewById(R.id.button);

            popupWindow.showAsDropDown(popupView, 0, 0);
```

Comment: This worked other than the fact, the popup window is now not centered

Comment: @SQLUser add your XML may i will help you to resolve this

Answer (score 1):

Normally you'd do this with a dialog and an OnCancelListener.  If you want the flexibility of a popup though, you can get the same things by setting it outside touchable, then calling setTouchInterceptor to intercept touches.  Remember to return false if the touch is inside the window, so it will go down the touch chain to the actual view.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that `popupWindow.showAsDropDown(popupView, 0, 0);`
is after these 
`popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
 popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
 popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));`

Comment: popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);  It helped me to dismiss popup window on click out side of dialog. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `setCanceledOnTouchOutside`?

Comment: How would I go about doing that ?

Comment: `Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context)
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);`

Answer (score 0):

You can use setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true) to close popup when user touch outside of popup.

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context)
dialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Let popup window setTouchable with true, and setTouchInterceptor and get return false, then you can click outside of popup window to close it.

```
popWindow.setTouchable(true);
popWindow.setTouchInterceptor(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return false;
    }
});
```

If it cannot work, please tell me, and I will see what I miss.

This answer is similar to Gabe Sechan's answer, and I just not discovered before I post this answer...

Answer (score 0):

2023 UPDATE: It has now been changed to `setCancelable`.

`dialog.setCancelable(true);`