# Dismissing PopupWindow the way PopupMenu can be dismissed by clicking outside

Tags: android, android-popupwindow

I develop an Android App for tablets. When the user clicks on a setting button I want to show the user a dialog on the upper right side of the screen where the settings can be configured.

Given that the dialog is complex I feel like `PopupWindow` is more appropriate then `PopupMenu`. `PopupMenu` has the nice behavior that it dismisses automatically when the user clicks outside of the menu. How do I get `PopupWindow` to behave the same way?

```
            val popupView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.popup_window, null)
            val popupWindow = PopupWindow(
                popupView,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            )
            popupWindow.showAsDropDown(appCompactImageButton, 20, 0)
```

Comment: This question looks similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12232724/popupwindow-dismiss-when-clicked-outside

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to set `setBackgroundDrawable` and `setOutsideTouchable` properties of `PopupWindow`  it should close the window if you touch outside of it.

```
PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(contentView, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable());
popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
```

Comment: Note: It seems to be important to call set... before `popupWindow.showAsDropDown`.

Comment: yes, if you call these properties after `popupWindow.showAsDropDown` than you must have to call `popupWindow.update()`

Answer (score 1):

// To close the popup window when touch outside.

```
mPopupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);
```

// Set focusable to popup window so that when touch it could dismiss the window

```
mPopupWindow.setFocusable(true);
```

// if you want to remove the default background.

```
mPopupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

> **setOutsideTouchable(boolean touchable)** Controls whether the pop-up
>   will be informed of touch events outside of its window.
>
> **setFocusable(boolean focusable)** 
>   Changes the focusability of the popup window.
>
> **setBackgroundDrawable(Drawable background)** Specifies the background
>   drawable for this popup window.

Answer (score 0):

I see `PopupMenu` close when you touch outside and when you click on back button. Therefore, to make `PopupWindow` can dismiss like `PopupMenu` you should use

```
popupWindow.isFocusable = true
// or you can send focusable when initialize PopupWindow because they have constructor like PopupWindow(View contentView, int width, int height, boolean focusable)
```

You can check [my full answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57086270/5381331) here to know why we should use `isFocusable`.