# I'm clicking inside my popup and it is closing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-popupwindow

Good afternoon, I am clicking inside the popupview, and it is closing, the behavior I hope is that the click event will only be triggered by clicking outside, but as you can see the popup is occupying the entire screen, is that the problem?

***as you can see the popup is occupying the entire screen, with a transparent background, but if I click inside the popup it closes***
[popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9IV6.png)

how could I center the popup using ConstraintLayout?

Code popup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:background="#80AAAAAA"
android:layout_margin="40dp"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:layout_margin="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_card_view"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    android:padding="20dp"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0">
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/pop_up_ocorrencias_constraint_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="8dp">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pop_up_ocorrencias_txt_cracha"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Marcações"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_list_marcacoes"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            tools:listitem="@layout/item_marcacao"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/pop_up_ocorrencias_txt_cracha"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/pop_up_ocorrencias_txt_cracha"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_txt_ocorrencias"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Ocorrências"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_list_marcacoes"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_list_marcacoes" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_txt_ocorrencias_api"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_txt_ocorrencias"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_txt_ocorrencias" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_txt_motivo"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Motivo"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_txt_ocorrencias_api"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_txt_ocorrencias_api" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_edt_motivos_api"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Motivo"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_txt_motivo"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_txt_motivo" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_txt_descricao"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Descrição"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_edt_motivos_api"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_edt_motivos_api" />
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_edt_descricao_api"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Descrição da ocorrência"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_txt_descricao"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_txt_descricao" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_txt_foto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Foto"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_edt_descricao_api"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_edt_descricao_api" />

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_constraint_foto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_txt_foto"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_txt_foto">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_txt_selecione_imagem"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Selecione uma imagem"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_image_selecione_imagem"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_image_selecione_imagem"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_cselect_image"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_constraint_foto_vizualizar_foto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_constraint_foto"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_constraint_foto">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                android:id="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_txt_vizualizar_foto"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:breakStrategy="high_quality"
                android:text="Vizualizar Foto"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_image_vizualizar_foto"
                android:layout_width="20dp"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_down"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_enviar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Enviar"
            android:background="@drawable/button_round"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_constraint_foto_vizualizar_foto"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_constraint_foto_vizualizar_foto" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

Code my class popup

```
public class PopUpOcorrencia {

//referencia https://medium.com/@evanbishop/popupwindow-in-android-tutorial-6e5a18f49cc7
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.Q)
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
public void showPopupWindow(final View view){
    //Crie você mesmo um objeto View através do inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) view.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.pop_up_enviar_ocorrencia, null);

    // Especifique o comprimento e a largura por meio de constantes
    int width = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    int height = ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;

    // Tornar itens inativos fora da PopupWindow
    boolean focusable = true;

    // Crie uma janela com nossos parâmetros
    final PopupWindow popupWindow = new PopupWindow(popupView, width, height, focusable);

    // Defina a localização da janela na tela
    popupWindow.showAtLocation(view, Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);

    popupWindow.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#80AAAAAA")));
    popupWindow.setFocusable(true);
    popupWindow.setOutsideTouchable(true);

    //popupWindow.setTouchModal(true);

    // Inicialize os elementos de nossa janela, instale o manipulador
    TextView test2 = popupView.findViewById(R.id.pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_txt_ocorrencias_api);
    test2.setText("Teste");

    Button buttonEdit = popupView.findViewById(R.id.pop_up_enviar_ocorrencias_enviar);
    buttonEdit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //As an example, display the message
            Toast.makeText(view.getContext(), "Wow, popup action button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });

    // Manipulador para clicar na zona inativa da janela
    popupView.setOnTouchListener((View v, MotionEvent event) -> {

        //Close the window when clicked
        popupWindow.dismiss();
        return true;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Popup closes because you are calling `popupWindow.dismiss();` inside `popupView.setOnTouchListener(...)`.

Comment: but how could I close the popup by clicking outside its area?

Comment: Have you tried the answers in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12232724/9455325)? I'm not sure if the answers are still valid because it's a 2012 question.